# observeSingleEvent is not triggering

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My observeSingleEvent is not being triggered. I set a breakpoint at the `let annotationRef..` and it goes through that, then to the `annotationRef.observeSingle..` and then skips right over the block of code under it to the end of the method. What could be the issue?

```
let annotationRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "annotationItems")                      
annotationRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in  
    // does not print
    print("IT WORKS")  
})
```

I have checked all related questions. Other things I've tried (and it still didn't work):

1) Turn off disk persistence

2) `let newRef = Database.database().child("annotationItems)
   newRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with { snapshot in`

3) observe vs. observeSingleEvent

4) Added a listener

This is my database structure

```
"annotationItems" : {
     "Apple Infinite Loop" : {
         "city" : "Cupertino",
     }
}
```

Comment: 1) if you put a breakpoint on the `print` statement, does it get triggered? 2) are you connected to a network?

Comment: 1) Okay that's weird. I put a breakpoint on the print statement and that gets triggered. However, if I put a breakpoint on the observe statement, the print statement doesn't get triggered. 2) What do you mean by that? I'm connected to the wifi and I assume my simulator is as well. I saw in another post that the observeSingleEvent sometimes gets triggered when tested on the device, but not in the simulator. Could this be the case?

Comment: Never mind. For some reason it works now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Good to hear zachenn!